# Rails: Error running 'bundle' command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

I am running `bundle install --local` and getting the following error:

`Your bundle is locked to rake (11.2.2), but that version could not be found in
any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that
means the author of rake (11.2.2) has removed it. You'll need to update your
bundle to a different version of rake (11.2.2) that hasn't been removed in order to install.`

Unable to decipher as to what needs to be done.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please Let me know the output of this command `bundle show | grep rack`

Comment: Actually we are running this in jenkins job and it is failing at this juncture.

Comment: Please try this in script `bundle update rack`.

Answer (score 4):

Try running these commands

```
gem install rubygems-bundler
gem regenerate_binstubs
```

Comment: I don't know what this is supposed to do, but it does not work. The simple solution is to delete the Gemfile.lock and then run bundle install to regenerate it again.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem also while using Jenkins, so here is what helped me:

First go through console to your job directory:

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<your-job-name>
```

If you are not sure where Jenkins stores your project, use `pwd` command inside your bash script.

In this directory, find your Gemfile.lock and delete it

```
rm Gemfile.lock
```

then try running bundle as you would usually do from console

```
bundle install
```

And see your bundle working. Hope it helps someone to solve the issue.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee the same gem versions are installed which were specified in the Gemfile.lock, so Jenkins might behave differently than your local environment.