# Rails Production: Bundle is locked to rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I've just added an export to PDF using the `wicked_pdf` gem to my application. It works fine on my development machine, but it keeps throwing the following error on the production server:

```
I, [2016-12-01T03:40:46.110058 #2857]  INFO -- :   Rendered reports/summary_of_reports.pdf.erb within layouts/pdf.html (24.3ms)
I, [2016-12-01T03:40:46.779291 #2857]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 698ms (ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)
F, [2016-12-01T03:40:46.780418 #2857] FATAL -- :
RuntimeError (Failed to execute:
["/home/ams/itdc_accounts/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "-q", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20161201-2857-1deugco.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20161201-2857-1snx0mz.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: /home/ams/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `rescue in specs': Your bundle is locked to rake (11.3.0), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of rake (11.3.0) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of rake (11.3.0) that hasn't been removed in order to install. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from /home/ams/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:173:in `specs'
        from /home/ams/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:233:in `specs_for'
        from /home/ams/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:222:in `requested_specs'
        from /home/ams/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
        from /home/ams/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
        from /home/ams/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
        from /home/ams/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
):
  app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in summary_of_reports'
  app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:15:in `summary_of_reports'
```

The things is that I've tried generating sample PDFs on the production server using the Rails console and it works, so I'm really confused as to why this is not working.

```
#view
<%= link_to icon("file-pdf-o") + " Export as PDF", request.parameters.merge({format: :pdf}), target: "_blank" %>

#controller
def summary_of_reports
  if params[:at].present?
    @account_type = AccountType.find_by_id(params[:at])
    @accounts_total = Account.where(account_type: params[:at]).joins(:user).order('users.last_name')
    @accounts = Account.where(account_type: params[:at]).joins(:user).order('users.last_name').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data Account.to_csv(@accounts_total), filename: "summary_of_reports_#{Time.now.strftime("%^b-%d-%Y-%H-%M")}.csv" }
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: "summary_of_reports_#{Time.now.strftime("%^b-%d-%Y-%H-%M")}",
        template: "reports/summary_of_reports.pdf.erb",
        locals: {
          accounts: @accounts_total,
          account_type: @account_type
        }
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the `rake` and `bundler` gems, as well as running `bundle install` and `bundle update` server-side to no use.

Update:
Added Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.13', '< 0.5'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'ffaker'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'shoulda-callback-matchers'
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false

  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger'
  gem 'rails-erd'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'thin'
end

gem 'simple_form'
gem 'momentjs-rails', :github => 'derekprior/momentjs-rails'
gem 'datetimepicker-rails', github: 'zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails', branch: 'master', submodules: true

gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'bootstrap'
# gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'google-webfonts-rails'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap4'

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_invitable'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'figaro'

gem 'searchkick'

gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

Update 2: Tried uninstalling and reinstalling all gem files, still no good.

Comment: Hm. I've seen this happen when a gem author yanks their gem version from rubygems, but weirdly 11.3.0 seems to be there on rubygems. What does your gemfile look like?

Comment: Updated the question with the Gemfile.

Comment: Okay, suspect #2 is wkhtmltopdf. This is a binary dependency that has to be installed for wicked pdf to work. You've probably installed it locally, but have you installed it in production?

Comment: Yes, I have it installed using the `wkhtmltopdf-binary` gem.

Comment: _scratches head_. Welp. I googled your error "Your bundle is locked to rake (11.3.0), but that version could not be found". Other folks have had your issue, but I don't see a silver bullet. Here are some resources to try the solutions of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722642/error-running-bundle-command, https://github.com/ruby/rake/issues/172, https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/5068.

Answer (score 0):

The `wkhtmltopdf` executable looks like it is an rbenv binstub, which boots up your bundled environment, but probably has dependency to `rake`.

Try adding

```
gem 'rake', '11.3.0'
```

to your `Gemfile`.

If that doesn't work, try creating a `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb` initializer with the path specified to the actual `wkhtmltopdf` binary on your production server (the one that shows up when you do `which wkhtmltopdf` on the command-line).